# insert data into associative table in mysql workbench using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i have 2 table: instrument and performance (many to many relationship). I want admin can create a performance which contain many instruments. But i have some error when insert into associative table. Associative table have perfprmanceId and instrumentId. I'm using sequelize. Here is my code:

admin controller:

```
postCreatePerformance = (req, res, next) => {
        const title = req.body.title;
        const date = req.body.date;
        const location = req.body.location;
        const instrumentNames = req.body.instrumentNames;
      
          req.user
            .createPerformance({
              title: title,
              date: date,
              location: location,
            })
            .then(createdPerformance => {
              return Instrument.findAll({
                where: { title: instrumentNames },
                attributes: ['id'],
              });
            })

            .then(instruments => {
                //insert data into associative table
                const performanceInstrumentData = instruments.map(instrumentId => ({
                  performanceId: createdPerformance.id,
                  instrumentId: instrumentId,
                }));
            
                
                return PerformanceInstrument.bulkCreate(performanceInstrumentData);

            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Created performance');
              res.redirect('/');
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error('Error creating performance or instruments:', error);
              // res.redirect('/');
            });
      };
```

And the error:

```
Error creating performance or instruments: ReferenceError: PerformanceInstrument is not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to `import` `PerformanceInstrument`

Comment: thanks, but i dont have that model, its table created automatically. But i just found one solution, here:
.then(createdPerformance => {
        return Instrument.findAll({
          where: { title: instrumentNames },
          attributes: ['id'],
        }).then(instruments => {

          createdPerformance.setInstruments(instruments).then(() => {
            console.log('Created performance');
            res.redirect('/');
          });
        });
      })

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you show us it seems that PerformanceInstrument is not defined in your code, it may be because you have not imported the PerformanceInstrument model correctly in your file.

Make sure that at the top of your file where you have your controller, you have imported the model.

Example:

```
const { PerformanceInstrument, Instrument } = require('../models'); // make sure you have the correct route
```